# How can handleEvent() be replaced by processEvent()?

Tags: java, swing, events

The [`handleEvent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#handleEvent%28java.awt.Event%29) component method is marked as deprecated and replaced with [`processEvent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#processEvent%28java.awt.AWTEvent%29).

But how can this replacing occur? `handleEvent()` was having a return value to indicate whether the event was processed or not, while `processEvent()` has no such return value.

So how does `processEvent()` signal that it was unable to process the event?

Answer (score 0):

In Java 1.1 the AWT event model was completely changed and replaced the `Event` class with the `AWTEvent` class, used up to (at least) Java 1.8. As with every major rewriting, it's hard to pinpoint an exact reason.

It's probable that since the `AWTEvent` has a `isConsumed` method there was no need for `handleEvent()` to return the value. The "is consumed \ processed" information is related to the event itself and not to a component, so it makes more sense for this informations to be returned from the event (`isConsumed`) and not the component (`processEvent()` \ `handleEvent()`). `Event` did not contain such information.